# react dropzone 400 Error when connect to api - nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, upload, react-dropzone

I used `react-dropzone-uploader.js` plugin for upload my files.

After Fetch to API, I got 400 Error.

I couldn't find solution but i think it's for `getUploadParams` part

```
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone-uploader'
import { getItem } from '../../../core/services/storage/storage';
const Preview = ({ meta }) => {
  const { name, percent, status } = meta
  return (
    <span>
      {name}, {Math.round(percent)}%, {status}
    </span>
  )
}

const CustomPreview = () => {
  const getUploadParams = ({ file, meta }) => {
    const token = getItem("token")
    const body = new FormData()
    body.append('fileField', file[0])
    return { url: 'https://myapi.net/Course/UploadFile', body, headers : {
      'Accept' : 'application/json',
       'Authorization': 'bearer '+  token
    } }
  }

  const handleSubmit = (files, allFiles) => {
    console.log(files.map(f => f.meta))
    allFiles.forEach(f => f.remove())
  }

  return (
    <Dropzone
      getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      PreviewComponent={Preview}
      inputContent="Drop Files (Custom Preview)"
      disabled={files => files.some(f => ['preparing', 'getting_upload_params', 'uploading'].includes(f.meta.status))}
    />
  )
}
<Preview/>
export default CustomPreview
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details about the API, it looks like you have problems with your headers.

`'Content-Type' : 'application/json'` should be omitted when submitting form data and `'Authorization': 'bearer'+  token` will result in something that looks like `bearermytoken` instead of `bearer myToken`, unless that space is built into your `getItem` function.

Comment: I omitted 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' and add space for token. still it has 400 error. i tested on api swagger, it's ok. i think problem is with getUploadParams

Comment: Do you get an error message with your response? And just to double check, what do you get when you `console.log(file[0])` in `getUploadParams`?

Comment: console.log(file) gives me this : File { name: "1.png", lastModified: 1675238158307, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 66701, type: "image/png" }

Comment: Looks like you need to append `file` to the body instead of `[file[0]`